# How to execute command inside launch file?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you run a command inside a launch file to set a param value?

I have launch file like:

```
<launch>
    <group ns="motor_arduino">
        <node pkg="rosserial_python" type="serial_node.py" name="serial_node" output="screen">
            <param name="~port" value="/dev/ttyACM0" />
            <param name="~baud" value="115200" />
        </node>
    </group>
</launch>
```

which allows communication with one of several Arduino Unos connected to the host computer. However, I've found that the mount path `/dev/ttyACM0` is variable, and based on how the Arduino's initialize, this may be `/dev/ttyACM0` or `/dev/ttyACM1`.

To fix this problem, I've written a script that reads the output of `udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/ttyACM*` and determines the correct device path to use. However, how do I call this script from inside the launch file to set the `port` param dynamically?

[The docs show](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML) that roslaunch does support some simply substitution commands, but I don't see a way to run an arbitrary script, e.g.

```
<param name="~port" value="$(identify_port.py device1)" />
```

gives me the error:

```
Unknown substitution command [identify_port.py device1]. Valid commands are ['find', 'env', 'optenv', 'anon', 'arg']
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257923/how-to-execute-command-inside-launch-file?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2017-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to use the `command` attribute, like so: `<param name="port" command="identify_port.py device1" />`. This will set the output of your script as the value of *port*.

Don't forget that the script should be in your `PATH` and have *execute* permission.

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.ros.org/users/20033/nlamprian/) with karma: 366 on 2017-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2020-05-28**:
It works. I tried with `<param name="any_name" command="rosrun <pkg_name> <executable_file>" />`

Comment: Is the same possible with launch file `arg`?

Comment: No, it's not. Arguments have either default or user-specified values. You can see the available attributes here http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg